# Set href of all links <a> in page javascript without some links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi guys please I want to set all href of links without the links in " Site_dont_go "

I was ask and get answer

this is answer

```
$("a").click(function() {
var x = $(this).attr("href");
var Site_dont_go = ["test.com", "youtube.com"];
var validUrl = true;
$.each(Site_dont_go, function(i, item) {
    if (x.indexOf(item) != -1) {
        validUrl = false;
    }
});

if (!validUrl) {
    window.open('goto.php?url=' + x);
    return false;
}
```

});

EDIT : 
**My qustion is : the answer working only when someone click on the link , and I want to set it as a href of link **

thanks and i'm so sorry

Comment: So what is the question if you got your answer already?

Comment: so do you want to set the hrefs of all anchors to one thing except for the pages that are in `Site_dont_go` ? I am pretty confused

Comment: Qustion has ben edito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should iterate all the  tags and change the hreff property. This should be done on document ready. Not tested code but should do the trick

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("a").each(function(index) {
            var x = $(this).attr("href");
            var Site_dont_go = ["test.com", "youtube.com"];
            var validUrl = true;
            $.each(Site_dont_go, function(i, item) {
                if (x.indexOf(item) != -1) {
                    validUrl = false;
                }
        });

        if (!validUrl) {
            $(this).attr("href",'goto.php?url=' + x);
        }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much ... I don't know why somebody give me -1 .... and him don't undestand what i say ... thank you again ... My respect for you

Comment: I have one quistion please , This will work on blogger !?

Comment: `x = $(this)[0].hostname.toLowerCase().replace(/^www\./, "");` for exact, case insensitive domain matches, `$.inArray()` is shorter

Comment: I think that should work. can't see why not since is just javascript (with jquery)

Comment: When I add it to blog nothing happening , and when I add the code with F12 (Console) ... I get message "TypeError: x is undefined"

Comment: You should check why x is undefined, maybe there is no href on some <a>

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to use something other than the click event to trigger the function. The `each()` method runs at load time.

```
$("a").each(function () { // <---------------- each!
    var x = $(this).attr("href");
    var Site_dont_go = ["test.com", "youtube.com"];
    ...
});
```

Don't forget to either place your script after your html or wrap it in `document.ready`.